# Отфильтровать строки при наличии в них слова

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, строки

Есть файл с таким содержанием:

```
name1@gmail.com
name2@yandex.ru
name3@gmail.com
name4@gmail.com
name5@mail.ru
name6@rambler.com
...
```

Есть такой код

```
SRC = 'mails.txt'  # Исходный файл
OUT = 'result.txt'  # Отфильтрованный
FILTR = ('@gmail.com',)


def grep_mail_names(src_list, filtr):
    """Возвратит массив имён, содержащих что-либо из filtr"""
    result = []  # Строки удобнее и быстрее собирать в list
    for line in src_list:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        for d in filtr:
            if d not in line:
                break
        else:
            result.append(line)
    return result



if __name__ == '__main__':

        with open(SRC, 'r') as src_file:
            file_1 = grep_mail_names(src_file.readlines(), FILTR)
        with open(OUT, 'w') as out_file:
            out_file.write('\n'.join(file_1))
```

В **FILTR** записываются домены строк, которые нужно оставить и записать в result.txt, но если добавить туда еще какой-нибудь домен, то все ломается. Туплю сильно, никак не могу исправить, что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас неправильная реализация фильтрации:

```py
for d in filtr:
    if d not in line:
        break
else:
    result.append(line)
```

Ветка `else` связана с циклом `for` и будет выполнена, только если цикл завершится без использования `break`.

То есть значение добавляется в список, если содержит **каждую** подстроку из `FILTR`.

---

Вам же нужно добавить значение, если оно содержит **хотя бы одну** подстроку:

```py
for d in filtr:
    if d in line:
        result.append(line)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def grep_mail_names(src_list, filtr):
    result = []
    for line in src_list:
        line = line.strip()
        if line[line.index('@'):] in filtr:
            result.append(line)

    return result
```